# PHP Variable Scope Inside Included Files

Tags: php, variables, scope, include

I have the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('ClassFile.php');
use ClassFile\Component;

include 'somefile.php';

?>
```

Within this template I can access properties of the Component (e.g. $comp = new Component();). However, Component is not visible from within somefile.php. I get an error  to the effect that it does not exist. The (poor) workaround is to copy the same code in somefile.php. Can anyone say what's going on? Do I need to somehow globalize the items in the require_once and use statements? Thanks.

Comment: What's in `somefile.php` that isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you cannot do `new Component` inside `somefile.php`, that's because the class is called `ClassFile\Component`, not `Component`. The `use` alias does not extend to included files. If you want to alias `ClassFile\Component` to `Component` in `somefile.php` too, you have to write the appropriate `use` statement in that file too.

Namespacing is always per-file.

Comment: Ah, so I can add another use statement within the include or reference it by its fully qualified name. Thanks.